# Two-dimensional dynamic array in C for Leetcode

Tags: arrays, c, dynamic

So i trying to solve https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/
But I don’t understand what I should pass to them in the **return_column_sizes variable and how to do it so that they start accepting the answers I return.

P.S.:I know my answers is just counter! **I want to understand what value in **return_column_sizes they want to receive from me**, after that I can write alghorythm by myself. Thats why i made just three triplets [0,1,2] [3,4,5] [6,7,8] and trying to answer with them, but Leetcode compiler dont understand my answer at all

Description from Leetcode:
/**

- Return an array of arrays of size *returnSize.
- The sizes of the arrays are returned as *returnColumnSizes array.
- Note: Both returned array and *columnSizes array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
  */

Here is my code:

```
int** dynamic_array_alloc(size_t N, size_t M)
{
    int **A = (int **)malloc(N*sizeof(int *));
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        A[i] = (int *)malloc(M*sizeof(int));
    }
    return A;
}

void dynamic_array_print(int **A, size_t N, size_t M)
{
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        printf("A[%d] = %p\t", i, A[i]);
        for (int j=0; j<M; j++)
            printf("%*d", 5, A[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int** threeSum(
  int* nums, int numsSize, 
  int* return_size, int** return_column_sizes
)
{
    int **result = dynamic_array_alloc(3, 3);
    int k=0;

    *return_size=3;
    *return_column_sizes=*result;

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++) result[i][j]=k++;

    dynamic_array_print(result, 3, 3);

    return result;
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tazKM.jpg)

Comment: The example code provided on Leetcode has documentation above the empty function, which details exactly what the parameters are.

Comment: OT: With an arithmetic "trick" you can use a one-dimensional array of size `N * M` as a "two-dimensional" array. It will have much better effectiveness than the [jagged array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array) you create.

Comment: @MrLeyt1125 The function threeSum does not make sense.

Comment: Isn't return_size the number of triplets you're returning? Your function doesn't process the input array nums at all. Are you hoping someone is going to just write the code for you? Leetcode is supposed to be used to learn, yet you've made no effort to actually solve the stated problem.

Comment: @SimonGoater I just want to understand what value in **return_column_sizes they want to receive from me, after that I can write alghorythm by myself. Thats why i made just three triplets [0,1,2] [3,4,5] [6,7,8] and trying to answer with them, but Leetcode compile dont understand my answer at all

Comment: @Unmitigated I just want to understand what value in **return_column_sizes they want to receive from me, after that I can write alghorythm by myself. Thats why i made just three triplets [0,1,2] [3,4,5] [6,7,8] and trying to answer with them, but Leetcode compiler dont understand my answer at all

Comment: @MrLeyt1125 I see what you mean now. I've provided an answer.

Comment: @Unmitigated So *return_size is number of answers (triplets) I returinng and **return_column_sizes is just [3,3,3] array, very wierd
Its worked though! Thx bro for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set each element of `*return_column_sizes` to 3.

```c
*return_size = 3;
*return_column_sizes = malloc(*return_size * sizeof *return_column_sizes);
for (int i = 0; i < *return_size; i++) (*return_column_sizes)[i] = 3;
```

Comment: It worked! Thx a lot!
The real question is why ffs they need malloced array of [3,3,,3] if the problem directly states that you need to return ONLY TRIPLETS

Comment: @MrLeyt1125 Happy to help. I don't understand why they have this strange output format either.

Answer (score 0):

return_column_size should be an array of size return_size containing 3, 3 and 3. While in the code return_column_size is an array of size 3 containing 0, 1 and 2 (the first column of result)